# Find all words in dictionary given a string of words

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a `program` that will find all the words that can be constructed from it using a dictionary which has been loaded into an `arrayList` from a `file`. sowpodsList is the dictionary stored as an `arrayList`. I want to `iterate` through each word in the dictionary and then compare it to the `string`. Being that the string is just a random collection of words how do I go about achieving this ?

Input: `asdm`

Output: `a, mad, sad ....` (any word which matches in the dictionary.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sowpodsList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sowpodsList.get(i).length(); j++) {
        if (sowpodsList.get(i).charAt(j) ==   )
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of input and output that you expected

Comment: Codegasmer - Input: asdm Output: a, mad, sad .... any word which matches in the dictionary.

Comment: fge - I am not familiar with implementing a trie structure. Do you have anything helpful I could reference.

Comment: In fact I have misread the question; a trie won't help...

Comment: Can you use a letter from the collection of random letters more than once? Do you have to scan the letters from left to right? For example, would `tac` still be valid for `cat`? Do you want to find multiple occurances of words? Please be more specific

Comment: The characters in the random collection can be implemented in any order and can only be utilized once. It would be similar to playing scrabble.

Comment: But scrabble allows the same letter multiple times, you know ;)

Comment: But then again, now that I think about it _agan_, a trie might have helped... Except that you'd need to store it in a peculiar format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search if the count of each character of each word in the dictionary is equal to the input's character count.

```
        ArrayList <String> matches = new ArrayList <String> ();

        // for each word in dict
        for(String word : sowpodsList) {

            // match flag
            Boolean nonMatch = true;

            // for each character of dict word
            for( char chW : word.toCharArray() ) {

                String w = Character.toString(chW);

                // if the count of chW in word is equal to its count in input, 
                // then, they are match
                if ( word.length() - word.replace(w, "").length() !=
                    input.length() - input.replace(w, "").length() ) {
                    nonMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (nonMatch) {
               matches.add( word );
            }
        }

        System.out.println(matches);
```

***Sample output:*** (dict file I used is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt)

```
Input: asdm
Matches: [ad, ads, am, as, dam, dams, ma, mad, mads, mas, sad]
```

Comment: It would not be a string of words but a random string of characters. E.g asdfsdsa . I would need to pull all the available words from it based off of my dictionary file .

Comment: @RunTheJewels I edited it. The concept is like in anagrams.

Comment: @raymefrancisco I am following your train of though when you tell me to sort the initial input into alphabetical order.  input = "hijokmnb" sorted input = "bhijkomn"  Then increment through comparing the the accumulated strings. How would this work with the dictionary( sowpods) since the strings in it will not be in alphabetical order ?

Comment: @RunTheJewels I also mentioned you should do the sorting in each word of the dictionary as well. :)

Comment: @raymefrancisco How would I reorder the words into a read fashion once I have sorted the dictionary ? e.g.   originally sad now : ads. Once I have a match how do I get it back to its original state to add it to the known word list ?

Comment: @raymefrancisco What would I use as an index counter ?

Comment: @RunTheJewels What do you mean? Btw, I edited my answer and you can try my shorter approach.

Comment: @raymefrancisco I am attempting to implement your first suggestions. I am not getting anything on the output though when I attempt to print words in  matches. I have verified the first two sorts of the input and of the dictionary.

Comment: @RunTheJewels I tested my first suggestion and its working fine. Same with my second. How did you print `matches` ?

Comment: @raymefrancisco for(String matchWords : matches){
   System.out.println(matchWords);
  }

Comment: @RunTheJewels Btw, I discovered some inconsistencies with my first method. Sorting won't detect all matches btw. I'm sorry for that but I have to remove it, my method 2 works fine and much shorter so maybe you can try that as well.

Comment: @raymefrancisco  Does anything need to be pre sorted for the second method ?

Comment: @RunTheJewels Nothing.

Comment: @raymefrancisco What is match and nonMatch at the bottom of the code ?

Comment: @RunTheJewels Just a typo. I edited my code. `match` is an `ArrayList` to hold the matches, while `nonMatch` is a `Boolean` flag used in checking for matches.

Comment: @raymefrancisco It seems to be working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RunTheJewels No problem.

Comment: @raymelfrancisco this solution is not completely correct. I tested this by making a sub dictionary list List<String> and added the following strings: a, add, bad, dad, cab. With the inputString = "abcd", it works correctly and i get the following words as output: a, bad, cab. However, if i add one more "d" to the inputString which makes it "abcdd", then i get the following words: a, add, dad, cab. Notice that "bad" was not matched. Can you help me figure out why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd change the way you store your dictionary.

Given that the string input has random letters in it, what I'd do here is store all words of your dictionary in a `SortedMap<String, char[]>` (a `TreeMap`, to be precise) where the keys are the words in your dictionary and the values are characters in this word *sorted*.

Then I'd sort the characters in the input string as well and go for that (pseudo code, not tested):

```
public Set<String> getMatchingWords(final String input)
{
    final char[] contents = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(contents);
    final int inputLength = contents.length;

    final Set<String> matchedWords = new HashSet<>();

    char[] candidate;
    int len;
    int matched;


    for (final Map.Entry<String, char[]> entry: dictionary.entrySet()) {
        candidate = entry.getValue();
        // If the first character of the candidate is greater
        // than the first character of the contents, no need
        // to continue (recall: the dictionary is sorted)
        if (candidate[0] > contents[0])
            break;
        // If the word has a greater length than the input,
        // go for the next word
        len = candidate.length;
        if (len > inputLength)
            continue;
        // Compare character by character
        for (matched = 0; matched < len; matched++)
            if (candidate[matched] != contents[matched])
                break;
        // We only add a match if the number of matched characters
        // is exactly that of the candidate
        if (matched == len)
            matchedWords.add(entry.getKey());
    }

    return matchedWords;
}


private static int commonChars(final char[] input, final char[] candidate)
{
    final int len = Math.min(input.length, candidate.length);
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (input[i] != candidate[i])
            break;
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

*With a trie*: that would also be possible; whether it is practical or not however is another question, it depends on the size of the dictionary.

But the basic principle would be the same: you'd need a sorted character array of words in your dictionary and add to the trie little by little (use a builder).

A trie node would have three elements:

- a map where the keys are the set of characters which can be matched next, and the values are the matching trie nodes;
- a set of words which can match at that node exactly.

You can base your trie implementation off [this one](https://github.com/fge/grappa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/grappa/matchers/trie) if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [TRIE](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-trie/) implementation.

TRIE provides the fastest way for searching over an Array of large collection of words.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

What you need to do is to insert all words into the trie data structure.

Then just need to call search function in Trie to get the boolean match info.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.  The best way depends on the relative size of the data structures.

If the dictionary is long and the list of letters is short, it may be best to sort the dictionary (if it is not already), then construct all possible words by permuting the letters (removing duplicates).  Then do a binary search using string comparison for each combination of letters to see if it is a word in the dictionary.  The tricky part is ensuring that duplicate letters are used only when appropriate.

If the list of letters is long and the dictionary is short, another way would be simply to count the number of letters in the input string: two a's, one s, one m, etc.  Then for each dictionary word, if the number of each individual letter in the dictionary word does not exceed those in the input string, the word is valid.

Either way, add all words found to the output array.